# How to edit html on a custom template

Tags: html

I'm a complete novice and have a question concerning an HTML custom template..... to remove team and coming soon from the main drop down menu what do I do?

Team

Clients

Reviews

FAQ

404 Page

Pricing

Coming Soon Page

Cheers

Comment: Open it in a text editor and edit it?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Expression Web 4.....I was told to use..... if you want to make inactive button replace <a href="team.html"> with <a href="#">  but it is not working.

Comment: If there's a way to edit the HTML in Expression Web 4 (I've never used it) then you can edit it there as well.  But this doesn't stop you from just opening the HTML file in, say, Notepad and editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your html file in a text editor and remove `<li>Team</li>` and `<li>Coming Soon Page</li>`